# Replacing the getHomeLink in Magento

Tags: magento, header

Can I just replace code `<?php echo $this->getHomeLink() ?>` in the header.phtml file copied below with `http://ourdomainname.com`?

Since our magento store is linked through navigation within our site, we want to use a link to our main domain in the header INSTEAD of using the store domain name.

Thanks for your help.

```
<div class="header-top"> 
<a href="<?php echo $this->getHomeLink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl($this->__('images/logo.gif')) ?>” alt="<?php echo $this->__('Magento Logo') ?>” class="logo"/></a> 
<div class="header-right"> 
<p class="super"> 
<?php echo $this->__("Logged in as %s", $this->getUser()->getUsername()) ?><span class="separator">|</span><?php echo $this->formatDate(null, 'full') ?><span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getLogoutLink() ?>” class="link-logout"><?php echo $this->__('Log Out') ?></a> 
</p> 
<?php if ( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin/global_search') ): ?> 
<fieldset> 
<legend>Search</legend> 
<span id="global_search_indicator" class="autocomplete-indicator" style="display: none"> 
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/ajax-loader.gif') ?>” alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading...') ?>” class="v-middle"/> 
</span> 
<?php $defSearch = $this->__('Global Record Search') ?> 
<input id="global_search" name="query" type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php if(!empty($query)): ?><?php echo $query ?><?php else: ?><?php echo $defSearch ?><?php endif ?>” onfocus="if(this.value==’<?php echo $defSearch ?>’)this.value=’’; “ onblur="if(this.value==’’)this.value=’<?php echo $defSearch ?>’;” /> 
<div id="global_search_autocomplete" class="autocomplete"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript\"> 
new Ajax.Autocompleter( 
‘global_search’, 
‘global_search_autocomplete’, 
‘<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/index/globalSearch') ?>’, 
{ 
paramName:"query", 
minChars:2, 
indicator:"global_search_indicator", 
updateElement:getSelectionId, 
evalJSON:’force’ 
} 
); 
function getSelectionId(li) { 
location.href = li.getAttribute(’url’); 
} 
</script> 
</fieldset> 
<?php endif; ?> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can. You can **do** whatever you want, you just need to live with the consequences of whatever action you take.

Comment: You sent me here via twitter. Thanks for the bit of snark;-) I still working through your book No Frills... Go easy.

Comment: Maybe it's a cultural thing, but that wasn't snark. Stack Overflow works best for clear questions with a clear answer, and the only clear question in your post was weather or not you could manually insert a link into a phtml template.  Which you can, but then you need to live with the consequence of not being able to edit this via the backend UI

Comment: Since the url and uri are identified elsewhere what consequences could there be? I only need to change the image to link to the main domain name. This is just a "dumb" link which needs to appear to be like the logo linked on the main domain. I just started this job and they set all this up weirdly but it will serve the purpose I think until I can do something more elegant.

Comment: see for your self as this url is defined in  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Header.php in getHomeLink() method as Alan said you can change this in template level, proper way would be however extending this block and rewrite the method to return the url you need

Comment: ok. I looked up the block at the Mage level but I am not sure how to rewrite. I am still learning.Does the replacement link go here? It needs to be http://ourdomainname.com NOT linked to the server where the magento store is.                                                               public function getHomeLink()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('adminhtml');